# openlayers popups wrong location

Tags: javascript, popup, openlayers

I have an application that is using OpenLayers 2.13.1. It is utilizing a bing
basemap and overlaying WMS layers. I am using a FramedCloud popup. I would
like the popup to appear where the user clicked and sometimes it does.
Sometimes it appears randomly to the east or west of where the user clicked.
Here is a snippet of code showing how I'm setting:

```
                boxSize = new OpenLayers.Size(450, 120);
                if (innovate.popupbox[mapID]) {

                    innovate.popupbox[mapID].lonlat = map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy);
                    innovate.popupbox[mapID].setContentHTML(content);
                    innovate.popupbox[mapID].setSize(boxSize);
                    //innovate.popupbox[mapID].panIntoView();
                    //innovate.popupbox[mapID].updatePosition();
                    innovate.popupbox[mapID].show();
                } else {
                    //first popup load - we will create a popup object
                    //and for next time we will reuse this object rather than creating a new one
                    innovate.popupbox[mapID] = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                            "innovate_info_popup_" + mapID,
                            map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy),
                            boxSize,
                            content,
                            null,
                            true
                            );

                    innovate.popupbox[mapID].panMapIfOutOfView = true;
                    innovate.popupbox[mapID].hide = function() {
                        this.div.style.display = 'none';
                        map.panTo(innovate.lastPopupCenter[mapID]);
                    }
                    map.addPopup(innovate.popupbox[mapID]);
                }
```

Comment: could you tuck this into a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(event.xy)` to get LonLat object instead of `map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy)`.

Not so rich (as wanted ;) explanation for [getLonLatFromViewPortPx](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx) and corresponding methods can be obtained from [documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html).

Comment: This didn't seem to fix the issue. The code is actually creating a popup the first time the user clicks. After the user closes the popup it reuses the popup the next time the user clicks on the map.

Comment: Try this method: http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Popup-js.html#OpenLayers.Popup.moveTo instead of direct changing lonlat value.

Comment: Thank you but that didn't seem to change the out come. It as if the coordinate in event.xy are wrong. I'm using the bing basemap if that makes as difference.

Comment: I've got some time ago the same problems and (as I can remember) solved it by using getLonLatFromViewPortPx instead of getLonLatFromPixel AND calling map.updateSize() on resize event of browser window (in my case I've used jQuery UI dialog window and map inside dialog). If your map container somehow resizes, try to call map.updateSize() - it should help.

Comment: So I re-worked the code so that it is not re-using the popups and that didn't seem to help. I've also been playing with map.updateSize() as you suggested. Is it possible that it could be some other section of code that could be causing such an inconsistant error? Maybe, the loading of the map?